# Formula to get days between dates?

Tags: formula, formula-field

Need to create a formula to calculate number of days between two date fields across objects.

I have created a formula field to calculate the number of days between two date fields:

```
Date Type = formula
Result = Number 
dummy__r.dummy_date__c - DATEVALUE( CreatedDate )
```

But this formula is not providing a value.

Comment: Is there a relation between the two objects?

Comment: It is lookup relation between objects .

Answer (score 3):

Formula = `(FieldValue1) - (FieldValue2)`.

You have to ensure that the `FieldValue1` and `FieldValue2` are of same type i.e.

1. Both should be DateTime or
2. Both should be Date  or
3. Both should be number.

Answer (score 1):

You can always format your field into a valid Date format:

```
DATE(YEAR(field__c), MONTH(field__c), DAY(field__c))
```

To calculate the number of days you can just deduct days:

```
DaysField1 - DaysField2
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be simple then:

```
Object1.date - objects2.date
```